# How to draw and update polygons in MapLibre in React Native Application?

Tags: react-native, maplibre-gl

Hy fellows,

I want to implement draw and update existing polygons on MapLibre Maps in React Native Application.I have gone through the [example](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/example/mapbox-gl-draw/) of the web.
but I can't find anything on how to achieve that in React Native Application.

Please help me to achieve that in my React Native Application ?